# Youtube API V3 how can i get channel username

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I need to use youtube username in a javascript script that retrieves data from youtube API with username

the problem is that this channel has a custom url in format:
https://www.youtube.com/c/myname

but from tutorial and video i found i need to get the user from a custom url like this
https://www.youtube.com/user/myname

since, as far as i know, is not possible to set an url and surname based on second url for newer channel how can i found the username?
any way to get it with API?

Comment: Do you have an example of the custom url? I don't recall seeing /c/ for YouTube.

Comment: @johnh10 e.g. https://www.youtube.com/c/annacavalli

Answer (score 1):

[youtube.channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) does NOT provide the username. you have to use Google+ API to get it.

Answer (score 0):

tube_dl is the answer.

```
pip install tube_dl
```

This module is a great video downloader and youtube parser.
Here's the sample code:

```
from tube_dl import Youtube
yt = Youtube('your video id').channelUrl
```

For tube_dl documentation, visit [Github Page of tube_dl](https://github.com/sheharchander/tube_dl)

Answer (score -2):

You can try out the [Channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method on the YouTube Data API. You can pass the username and it will return the list of channels that said user have.

The [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) developer site has more information if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: If I get it right he is trying to get the username of a custom youtube url. In this case youtube.channels.list will not help.